# How to filter a trend?

Tags: r, filtering, rscript, trend

Is it possible to filter a trend like this:

```
set.seed(1)
n=1000
mu = c(rep(1,100),rep(3,100),rep(5,100),rep(2,100),rep(1,600))
y = mu + rnorm(n)
```

and then obtain a numerical vector that defines the new trend?
It would be optimal if you could also use different threshold values

[image]

Comment: Could you make your question more precise? What do you mean by "filter a trend"? What kind of filter? Actually, what do you mean by "trend", because there is a multitude of tools to detect and analyse trends.

Comment: I try to explain myself better. I would like to be able to get a cleaner and more linear trend. This will help me to look for peaks and valleys in the graph later

Comment: You could try the mFilter package https://cran.r-project.org/package=mFilter "The mFilter package implements several time series filters useful for smoothing and extracting trend and cyclical components of a time series." Searching for "pass filter" will get you several other functions and packages.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you are looking for a smoothing function. There are many ways to achieve this: for example rolling average, loess, generalized additive models. If you want the trend to be composed of straight line sections, as in your example, you could try a regression with b-splines and degree 1.

This little function would perform such a task:

```r
library(splines)

smoother <- function(x, n = floor(length(x) / 10), deg = 1) {
  predict(lm(y ~ bs(seq_along(y), knots = seq(1, length(y), n), degree = deg)))
}
```

The `x` argument is the data from which you are trying to find the trend, and `n` is the number of measurements between knots (that is, the points where the gradient of the line can change). `deg` is the degree of the polynomial used (1 for straight line segments, and higher numbers for smoother polynomial fits).

Trying this on your example, we would get something like this:

```
plot(y, type = 'l')

trend <- smoother(y, 50)
lines(trend, col = 'red')
```

[image]

Or if you wanted a less jagged line:

```r
plot(y, type = 'l')
lines(smoother(y, 75, 4), col = 'red')
```

[image]